# i build a form with multiple textboxes and i want to convert this form to pdf

Tags: c#

i tried this but but when i run it and click the convert button i recieve this
"A generic error occurred in GDI+"
I don't know what else to try I'm a new programmer 
please help me

```
    private void captureScreen()
    {

        try
        {
            Rectangle bounds = this.Bounds;
            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
            {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {
                    g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                }
                bitmap.Save("C://Rectangle.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        captureScreen();

        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();

        PdfPage oPage = new PdfPage();

        doc.Pages.Add(oPage);
        oPage.Rotate = 90;
        XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(oPage);
        XImage img = XImage.FromFile(@"C://Rectangle.bmp");

        xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);

        doc.Save("C://RectangleDocument.pdf");
        doc.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Other than you've used the wrong slashes... where exactly is your error happening?

Comment: @BugFinder the error happen when i click on button 3.. what do you mean wrong slashes if i choose the other slash i get multiple errors

Comment: if you write @"c:\rectangle.bmp" you shouldnt get any errors at all. and exactly which line of code is it erroring at.... thats my point

Comment: thats why im confused, no errors in code i just get meesage box "A generic error occurred in GDI+" without real errors

Comment: i got an exception "The file 'C:\Rectangle.bmp' does not exist"

Comment: I fixed it i only had to change the path to d it run with no errors for somehow i guess its administrator privileges thing.
i feel so stupid

Comment: thats cos you wrote it to c:\, if you put it in temp, it would have been fine